# Stack for dynamic tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I do stack for tensors with dynamic shape. For example:

```
Tensor1.shape = [252, 921, 3]
Tensor2.shape = [591, 362, 3]
Tensor3.shape = [840, 125, 3]
Tensor4.shape = [292, 253, 3]
```

and `stack([Tensor1, Tensor2, Tensor3, Tensor])` must give output Tensor with shape [4, ?, ?, 3]

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't. Your dimensions are not the same and they can't be reshaped to a common shape. Depending on what you are doing, you could pad your tensors to have the same sizes.